# error in installing authlogic in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, authlogic, bundle

hello
i want to use authlogic with rails 3.1
i have pasted following code in the gem file

"gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'  #http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/37-authlogic-and-rails-3-0-solution"
and then trying to do bundle install.
but getting the error like this

"Fetching git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
An error has occurred in git when running `git clone "git://github.com/odorcicd/
authlogic.git" "c:/jruby-1.6.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/authlogic
-6baa44cd7023e0828fc87e150aa82c0caeeb7c3d" --bare --no-hardlinks`. Cannot comple
te bundling."

i have tried the command "gem install authlogic" and its successfully installed the gem
but then also facing the same error in bundle install

can anyone help me?
thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`gem 'authlogic'` in your Gemfile will be enough

Comment: @Russell, are you joking? `Rails 3.1`? Are we  talking about 3.1?

Comment: nope, not joking, checkout the link I posted - I've been trying out rails 3.1beta and running in to small issues in a good chunk of gems I'm using, including authlogic

Comment: @Russell, **Please note the latest version is
compatible with rails 3 only. Rails 2 should
use version 2.X.X**

Comment: @Rusell, I was answering about Rails 3.0.x not about 3.1.x

Comment: The latest version is not compatible with rails 3.1 though .. which is what the poster was asking about : "hello i want to use authlogic with rails 3.1" .. you're answer would work perfectly for rails 3.0.7

Comment: no prob :) I was hoping to stumble on a solution, but looks like only patches are available at the moment